# android google+ sign in repeatedly displaying permissions screen for signed up users

Tags: android, google-plus

I’ve implemented google+ sign in with the [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) class using ‘Cross-client Identity’ method as described [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth). My app uses the following scopes:

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/
http://gdata.youtube.com
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

The first time a user signs in all the scopes are shown to the user in a single screen and clicking sign-in works fine. The trouble begins once the user has signed in for the first time; Any subsequent sign ins (logging out of the app and attempting to sign back in) leads the user to the following scenario:

- User is presented with google permissions screen again (despite already having granted permission to this application for this account)
- This time around (not first sign in) the permissions screen is split to two, the first one only shows the youtube scope:

  [image: first scope screenshot]
- The second one shows the rest of the scopes (including youtube again):

  [image: second scopes screenshot]

Does anybody know why the permissions screen is displayed again if the user has already accepted these scopes for this account?
More over why are the scopes split to two different screens the second time around?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful when implementing that flow to avoid this problem. The important thing to know is that the request for the code (e.g.  oauth2:server:client_id:CLIENTID:api_scope:SCOPES) will *always* require a consent dialog to be displayed. The proper flow you should use:

1. Retrieve an ID token for the user (this does not require consent)
2. Send this to the server to determine whether it requires a new (refresh) token for this user.
3. If the server has one, it should generate an access token from the refresh token
4. If it does not, the client should retrieve one, which will require the user to consent.

With regards to the double consent screen - will probably need to see your code to answer that. A common cause is retrieving an access token with GoogleAuthUtil, and then retrieving the code (the consent dialog already seen for the access token *does not count* for the code retrieval, so it causes another). Its possible there is an issue around the youtube scope, but retrieving multiple tokens feels most likely.